# Изобретать ли велосипед?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Сразу оговорюсь, помощи по конкретному коду не требуется.

Начал писать приложение, причем не используя фреймворки, изобретать велосипед. Но, натолкнулся на пару полуобсуждений-полухоливаров, в которых ведется спор велосипед-vs-фреймворк, и это жутко выбило меня из колеи, так что требуется Ваше авторитетное мнение по конкретной задаче.

Итак.

Грубо говоря, требуется сайт. Точнее - целый http-сервер. Крайне желательно на джаве (можно сказать, что прихоть). Требования - очень высокая нагрузочная способность, максимальная латенси, прямая работа с сокетами (для общения с другим сервером, но не http), базовая защита от взлома (хотя бы на уровне "че это за фигня?!" со стороны взломщика), работа с файловой системой (причем, кешируемый доступ) и субд (аналогично, пулы подключений), возможность адекватного планирования тасков (крон, ага). Ну и ещё несколько мелочей.

Доступ со стороны клиента планируется только простыми GET и POST запросами, плюс куки, плюс аякс. Кип-элайв и мультипарт вряд ли когда-либо понадобятся.

Доступ с другой стороны - постоянное соединение с мастер-сервером (игровым), плюс консоль, плюс SSH.

Тут, собственно, и встает вопрос выбора платформы. PHP (как минимум - отсутствие адекватных сокетов и лютая неприязнь к нему), Ruby и другие языки (незнание языка и привычка к джава/шарп) - не подходят по понятным соображениям. Требуется именно ООП со всеми вытекающими. Выбор пал на джаву, как на самый любимый мой язык, и за её кроссплатформенность.

Дальше выбор встал уже за описанным выше холиваром - всё таки фреймворк или собственный велосипед?

Выше я описал требования, особенно сильно они касаются быстродействия, возможности подключения очень большого количества пользователей, и хотя бы некой устойчисовтью к DDOS.

Посмотрел я на различные монструозные фреймворки типа томката и подобного - мне они показались черезчур сложными и тяжеловесными. Если использовать их под мои требования - получится то же самое, что и поездка на личном белазе за хлебом в ларек. Можно, но нахрена?

Сроки разработки совершенно не важны, их ни кто не ставит.

Соображения вхождения не важны - пишу только я.

Сейчас есть основная часть http-сервера, написанная мной. Ни чего лишнего: только GET/POST, только close соединения. Всё обрабатывается простыми сокетами с пулом потоков (1 соединение = 1 поток в очередь и дальше в пул). Файлы кешируются по размеру, плюс чистятся периодически, а так же перезагружаются лениво при их изменении. Соединение с БД тоже через пул соединений и через пакет c3p0 (и дальше по пакетам до mysql-connector) - тут я не стал писать свой огород, mysql-connector довольно легкий, и ненужных мне реализаций в нем нет.

Натравливал 5 экземпляров Siedge с разных компьютеров в локальной 1гбит сети - такой сервер даже не поперхнулся. HOIC'и же сами быстрее сваливаются, чем нагружают сервер хоть как-то.

Запускается всё элементарно - запустил mysql, запустил джава приложение. Всё. Ни какх телодвижений с деплоем и прочими малоизвестными мне шаманствами.

Да, я понимаю, что наверняка в моем коде есть ошибки и недочеты, его придется неспешно допиливать, править баги и т.д.

Так вот, собственно, вопрос: есть ли смысл заглядываться на тяжелые фреймворки, которые я ни когда не использовал, и которые, как я понял, приходится очень непросто настраивать и поднимать? Но ведь они проверены годами и миллионами пользователей... И если смысл таки имеется, то посоветуйте наиболее легкий (как по весу, так и по освоению) фреймворк, и какую-нибудь русскую информацию по нему. Всё, что мне требуется от него - просто передача реквеста (RAW) в постоянно запущенное приложение на джаве и посылка ответа на него (аналогично, RAW).

Фух, выговорился, спасибо за внимание. :)

Comment: Если вас интересует именно "максимальная латенси", то нужно выбирать самый тяжелый и тормозной фреймворк :) А вообще вопрос крайне холиварный, и любое авторитетное мнение по факту будет являться религиозным.

Comment: Я для начала взял бы библиотеки и по быстрому собрал работающий прототип. Фрейворки не брал бы - они навязывают определенный стиль проекта - так просто потом не выпилишь. Когда все заработает (главное, что бы правильно), можно будет подумать, а стоит ли переписывать библиотеку, которая раз час отправляет на почту отчет. А вот в узких местах - там можно и переписать красиво, на чистых сокетах и с прямым доступом к памяти с чистым С (если нужно конечно).

А сейчас думать "ой, у меня тут тормозить будет - напишу с нуля". Да не будет оно там тормозить (иначе не задавали бы таких вопросов).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно, фреймворк. Я никогда не заморачиваюсь такими вещами - беру фреймворк и все тут. Это не вопрос холивара, а вопрос профессионализма. Холивар это какой фреймворк взять - это да. Тут можно очень долго спорить какой, но советую обратить внимание на learning curve конкретного фреймворка, то есть по русски говоря, сколько усилий надо приложить, чтобы выучить фреймворк. Есть такие фреймворки, на изучение которых надо положить полжизни, а есть такие которые можно понять за полчаса. Кстати, Tomcat считается простым :) - конечно, в последних версиях там много чего навертели, но в целом это достаточно простая компактная система. Оттуда выкинуть (не использовать) всякие фичи связанные с кластеризацией и проч. и можно получить вполне понятный и простой сервер. В оконцове попробуйте Jetty, по сути у него ядро ранних версий Tomcat'а (по-моему). Недавно знакомые хвалили Winstone - что за зверь не знаю, говорят очень легкий и простой. Попробуйте, потом расскажете :)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на [Spring](http://spring.io/)

Comment: Вот-вот как раз тот случай когда на его изучение надо положить полжизни :)

Comment: Не думаю - там есть простейшие примеры, от них начинать и постепенно усложнять.